# How to consume WCF service methods by ajax getJSON?

Tags: c#, ajax, wcf, getjson

It's a code that was created in Visual Studio 2013 by default wizard.
In project properties I set it to use Local IIS.
WCF Test Client test it successfully.
In the same project I added html page, which trying to get method by getJSON, but I'm getting and error "Not Found" from .fail section
What should I modify in order to consume it by getJSON?
Note: I understand method  GetTime is also "invisible" in browser ("400 Bad Request"), and I need to configure endpoints, I looked it up, but my attempts unsuccessful..

IService1.cs

```
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.ServiceModel;
namespace WcfService1
{
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IService1
    {
        [OperationContract]
        string GetTime();
    }
}
```

Service1.svc.cs

```
using System;
namespace WcfService1
{
    public class Service1 : IService1
    {
        public string GetTime()
        {
            return DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString();
        }
    }
}
```

web.config

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>

  <appSettings>
    <add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5"/>
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <protocolMapping>
        <add binding="basicHttpsBinding" scheme="https" />
    </protocolMapping>    
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
    <directoryBrowse enabled="true"/>
  </system.webServer>

</configuration>
```

HTMLPage1.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
    <body>
        <div>
            <span id="jspan"></span>
        </div>
</html>

<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var prom = $.getJSON("http://localhost/Service1.svc/GetTime");

        prom.done(function (data) {
            $("#jspan").text("data: " + data.d);
        })
            .fail(function (data) {
                $("#jspan").text("error: " + data.statusText);
            });

    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to access web service method by ajax, I need to be able to access it by http (to see it in the browser).
So first step is to configure web service behavior for this. I answered on it here:
[How to access WCF service methods from browser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25314578/how-to-access-wcf-service-methods-from-browser/25318726)
Then we call our ajax method "as usual". Code attached below.

IService1.cs

```
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.ServiceModel.Web;
namespace WcfService1
{
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IService1
    {
        [OperationContract]
        [WebGet]
        string GetTime();
    }
}
```

web.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>

  <appSettings>
    <add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5"/>
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>

      **<!--added behavior-->
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="WcfService1.Service1AspNetAjaxBehavior">
          <enableWebScript />
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>**

    </behaviors>
    <protocolMapping>
        <add binding="basicHttpsBinding" scheme="https" />
    </protocolMapping>

    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />

    **<!--added service behaviour configuration-->
    <services>
      <service name="WcfService1.Service1">
        <endpoint address="" behaviorConfiguration="WcfService1.Service1AspNetAjaxBehavior"
          binding="webHttpBinding" contract="WcfService1.IService1" />
      </service>
    </services>**

  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
    <directoryBrowse enabled="true"/>
  </system.webServer>

</configuration>
```

HtmlPage1.html with java script

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
    <body>
        <div>
            <span id="jspan"></span>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>

<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var prom = $.getJSON("http://localhost/WcfService1/Service1.svc/GetTime");

        prom.done(function (data) {
            $("#jspan").text("data: " + data.d);
        })
            .fail(function (data) {
                $("#jspan").text("error: " + data.statusText);
            });

    });
</script>
```

result should look like this:

[image: Client app and method in the browser screen shot]